# How to avoid/prevent column header and column footer without details

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I've got a report with several sub-reports.

**Report:**

```
Sub-Report 
Sub-Report
```

To seperate them a little bit, I put a frame around all the data in the sub-report.

**Sub-Report:**

```
Column Header: 
- Frame (left,top,right) 
Group Header 1:
- Headings of data
Detail 1: 
- data 
- Frame (left,right) 
Group Footer 1: 
- summary of data 
- Frame (left,right) 
Column Footer: 
- Frame (left,bottom,right)
```

So when the remaining place on a side is not big enough, there will just appear column header and footer.

-> How to avoid that?

**Situation on page:**

```
Column Header
Group Header 1
Detail 1 
Group Footer 1
Column Footer 

Column Header
-nothing else here-
Column Footer
-- next page --
Column Header
Group Header 1
Detail 1
Group Footer 1
Column Footer
```

**What I want on the page:**

```
Column Header 
Group Header 1 
Detail 1 
Group Footer 1
Column Footer 

-- next page --
Column Header 
Group Header 1 
Detail 1 
Group Footer 1 
Column Footer
```

BTW: I also tried using *Page Header/Footer* instead of *Column*. But it didn't worked, either. And I putted the frames also in *Group Header/Footer*, but in this case, when data needs more than one page, there is no frame on bottom of page, cause group footer is at the end of the group.

Or to say it with other words: I would only see column/page footer/header, if there is data details-band with data visible.

My *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Subreport" pageWidth="566" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="566" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" resourceBundle="ReportResources" whenResourceMissingType="Key">
    <parameter name="JasperReportParm.FromMaster.PK" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <parameter name="JasperReportParm.FromMaster.Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="JasperReportParm.FromMaster.Datum" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM ...]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="PK" class="java.lang.Long">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="PK1" class="java.lang.Long">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="ZahlFormatted" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="zebra" class="java.lang.Boolean">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[false]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <group name="FramesTopBottom" isReprintHeaderOnEachPage="true" minHeightToStartNewPage="79">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="2"/>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band/>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <group name="PK1" isReprintHeaderOnEachPage="true" minHeightToStartNewPage="40">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{PK1}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="29">
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="487" y="6" width="74" height="10"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font fontName="Helvetica" size="9" isItalic="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{JasperReportParm.FromMaster.Datum}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <rectangle>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="17" width="566" height="9" backcolor="#AFD9FF"/>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </rectangle>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement key="4" x="5" y="18" width="52" height="9"/>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Helvetica" size="7" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$R{Global.Datum}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="566" height="29"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.1" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.1" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.1" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                </frame>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="24">
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="495" y="3" width="67" height="1" forecolor="#999999"/>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.1" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </line>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="496" y="7" width="65" height="10"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font fontName="Helvetica" size="9" isBold="true" isItalic="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{ZahlFormatted}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="566" height="24"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.1" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.1" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.1" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                </frame>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="8" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="566" height="2"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.1" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.1" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.1" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.1" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="11" splitType="Stretch">
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement key="2" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="566" height="11" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" backcolor="#ECF4FF">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{zebra}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="566" height="11"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.1" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.1" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.1" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="8" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="566" height="8"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.1" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.1" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.1" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.1" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Is your subreport in a detail band? Can you post your JRXML file?

Comment: @Lisa: I did and now?!?